# What happen with a condition on a case?

Tags: ruby

I was playing today and accidentally end up writting this, now I'm courious.

```
i = 101
case i
  when 1..100
     puts " will never happen "
  when i == 101
     puts " this will not appear "
  else
     puts " this will appear"
end
```

How ruby internally process `when i == 101` is like `i == (i == 101)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure

```
case a
  when x
    code_x
  when y
    code_y
  else
    code_z
end
```

evaluates identically to

```
if x === a
  code_x
elsif y === a
  code_y
else
  code_z
end
```

Each `when` calls the method `===` on the argument of `when`, passing the argument of `case` as the parameter (`x === a` is identical to `x.===(a)`). The `===` method is slightly different than `==`: it is typically called "case subsumption". For simple types like numbers and strings, it is the same thing as `==`. For `Range` and `Array` objects, it is a synonym for `.include?`. For `Regexp` objects, it is quite similar to `match`. For `Module` objects, it tests whether the argument is an instance of that module or one of its descendants (basically, if `x === a` then `a.instance_of?(x)`). Thus, in your code,

```
if (1..101) === i
  ...
elsif (i == 101) === i
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

which performs pretty much the same tests as

```
if (1..101).include?(i)
  ...
elsif (i == 101) == i
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Note that there is another form of `case` that does not employ `===`:

```
case
  when x
    code_x
  when y
    code_y
  else
    code_z
end
```

which is identical to

```
if x
  code_x
elsif y
  code_y
else
  code_z
end
```

Comment: Readers: if you see some similarity between this answer and mine, you should know that my my original answer was an incorrect mess, which did not go unnoticed by this lime-helmeted Rubiest. He submitted his answer around the same time as I completed my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (1..100) === 101
  puts " will never happen "
elsif (101 == 101) === 101 
  puts " this will not appear "
else
  puts " this will appear"
end
```

If we look at [Range#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) we see that

```
(1..100) === 101
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1..100).include?(101)
   #=> false
```

`(101 == 101) === 101` reduces to:

```
true === 101
```

We see from the doc for [TrueClass#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) that this is equivalent to:

```
true == 101
  #=> false
```

Hence, the else clause is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `when i == 101` its equivalent to:

```
i == (i == 101)

which for your code is equal to

101 == true # false

if you do the when case as follows:

when i == 101 ? i : false
```

It will enter to that block section

```
i = 101
case i
  when 1..100
     puts " will never happen "
  when i == 101 ? i : false
     puts " THIS WILL APPEAR "
  else
     puts " this will now NOT appear"
end
#> THIS WILL APPEAR
```

Comment: You should use a proc instead, i.e. `when -> (j) { j == 101 }`